# How to check if a variable matches any item in list using the any() function?

Tags: python, python-2.x

Edit: This is what I am trying to do:
I am asking the user to enter a month. then the code will lookup if the month is correct by checking every item in months_list. If not found I want him/her to enter the month again..

Here's the code:

```
months_list=["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"]
answer=raw_input("Month? \n")
while any(item.lower() != answer.lower() for item in months_list):
    print("Sorry, didn't recognize your answer, try again")
    answer=raw_input("Type in Month\n")
```

However this keeps looping regardless if the month is found in the list or not.. I hope this is a good clarifaction.. thank you all in advance

Comment: Your expectation of `any` is wrong.  It'd check whether the iterable is empty or not.

Comment: The "proper" way to use `any` here is `any(x == 'A' for x in a)`, but you should just use `in`.

Comment: Is what you're trying to do not working in some way -- what's your question?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is that `any()` returns `True` if any **one** of the elements in the iterable is `True`, so your code keeps looping as long as the answer isn't equal to *all* the strings in `months_list`—which is probably the opposite of what you want to happen. Here's a way to use it that stops or breaks-out of the loop if the answer matches *any* of the strings:

```
months_list = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"]

while True:
    answer = raw_input("Month? ")
    if any(item.lower() == answer.lower() for item in months_list): 
        break
    print("Sorry, didn't recognize your answer, try again")
```

As others have pointed out, while it would simpler to use Python's `in` operator, that way still results in a linear search, ***O(n)***, being performed…so an even better (faster) approach would be to use a `set` of lower-cased `month_names`, which would utilize a hash table based look-up, ***O(1)***, instead of a linear search:

```
months = set(month.lower() for month in ("January", "February", "March", "April",
                                         "May", "June", "July"))
while True:
    answer = raw_input("Month? ")
    if answer.lower() in months: 
        break
    print("Sorry, didn't recognize your answer, try again")
```

**Further refinement**

Depending on the nature of strings involved and why you're comparing them, it might be better to use the string [`casefold()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) method instead of `lower()` to do caseless string comparisons.

Answer (score 24):

`any(a)` means "is any item in `a` truthy"? And the result is `True` because every item in `a` is truthy. (Any non-zero-length string is truthy, and every item in `a` is a non-zero-length string.)

And then you are comparing that result, `True`, to, say, `"A"`. `True` is not equal to `"A"` so the result of *that* comparison is, of course, `False`.

What you probably want to do is something like:

```
"A" in a   # True
```

If you must use `any()` for some reason, try:

```
any(item == "A" for item in a)
```

This approach has the advantage of being able to do imprecise comparisons easily (`in` will only do exact comparisons).  For example:

```
any(item.lower() == "a" for item in a)   # case-insensitive
any("a" in item.lower() for item in a)   # substring match
any(item.lower().startswith("a") for item in a)
```

Comment: Thank you .. this is exactly what I am trying to accomplish .. however still no luck. I've edited my question for you

Comment: That is now a totally different question from the one I answered, making this answer completely useless.  :-(

Comment: Well, technically I wouldn't say "useless", maybe just "out of context". I landed here after googling "python list anymatch" and your code example gave me what I wanted in a few seconds. So it's a particularly useful out of context answer, at least in my experience.

Answer (score 13):

To check membership, use `in`:

```
>>> a = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> 'a' in a
True
>>> 'z' in a
False
```

Comment: I'm not the OP, but I had a similar question and this is exactly what I was looking for! thanks!